# How to send value from Ajax to my Symfomy controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to pass a coming form a select list from ajax to my symfony code but the ajax script  return error message.

Twig file:

```
function changeStatus(sel){
    var status_id = sel.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ path('report_leads_change_status') }}',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'leadStatusId': status_id },
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Erreur, la connexion au serveur a été interrompue');
        }
    });
```

Routing file:

```
report_leads_change_status:
    path:      /leadStatus
    defaults:  { _controller: MerchantBundle:Report:changeLeadStatus }
    methods: "post"
```

and the controller:

```
public function changeLeadStatusAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->request->get('leadStatusId')){

    }

    return $this->render('MerchantBundle:Report:leadsHistory.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether AJAX or Symfony is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line in your ajax code.

```
url: "{{ path('report_leads_change_status') }}",
data: { leadStatusId: status_id },
```

You might getting a syntax error because of this?

Edit

---

Remove this lines.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: i change the code but i have  the same error result

Comment: error: function(){
                                alert('Erreur, la connexion au serveur a été interrompue');
                            }

Comment: i have the message of error function (in the code that i send you)

Comment: check in your console if the ajax is working and sending data as expected?

Comment: i haven't a message in my console,  when i put in my error function this console.log(msg) i have this in my console :

Comment: In console go to network tab and check if ajax is sending request to the mentioned url?

Answer (score 0):

on routing methods must an array, methods: "post" change to methods: [post]